# Populate the nth form element with the nth value of an array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I would like to know how to populate the nth hidden field, with the nth value of the array I've created below using jQuery. I've successfully created an array that groups the 3 checkbox options (if they are checked) in parentheses into the array. EX: [(A,B),(A,C),(A,B,C)...].

I now need to get the nth value in the array and populate the nth hidden field with that value.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_0" id="opt_0" class="get_options">
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_1" id="opt_1" class="get_options">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="registrant">
                <td><input type="text" id="OETIPC-NAME0" name="OETIPC-NAME0"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-A0" id="OETIPC-A0" class="reg_type" value="A"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-B0" id="OETIPC-B0" class="reg_type" value="B"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-C0" id="OETIPC-C0" class="reg_type" value="C"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="registrant">
                <td><input type="text" id="OETIPC-NAME1" name="OETIPC-NAME1"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-A1" id="OETIPC-A1" class="reg_type" value="A"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-B1" id="OETIPC-B1" class="reg_type" value="B"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="OETIPC-C0" id="OETIPC-C1" class="reg_type" value="C"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

// Get registration option values and group for each row then create array
$('.registrant').each(function() {
  var attendee_reg_type = $(this).find('.reg_type:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
});
```

I need to now output something similar to the following:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_0" id="opt_0" class="get_options" value="(A,B)">
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_1" id="opt_1" class="get_options" value="(A,C)">
    ...
```

Can someone help? I'm a little lost on the best way to do this. I did try the following, but with no success:

```
$('.registrant').each(function() {
  var attendee_reg_type = $(this).find('.reg_type:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  $('#opt_[i]').val(attendee_reg_type[i]);
});
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What, and where, is/are the `.registrant' element(s)?

Comment: Ooops, sorry about that @DavidThomas. .registrant is the class on the rows of the table. I edited my issue above to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply remove the hidden fields and rename your checkboxes like this:

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="OETIPC-NAME0" name="OETIPC-NAME0"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_0" id="OETIPC-A0" class="reg_type" value="A"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_0" id="OETIPC-B0" class="reg_type" value="B"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_0" id="OETIPC-C0" class="reg_type" value="C"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="OETIPC-NAME1" name="OETIPC-NAME1"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_1" id="OETIPC-A1" class="reg_type" value="A"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_1" id="OETIPC-B1" class="reg_type" value="B"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="opt_1" id="OETIPC-C1" class="reg_type" value="C"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Now on submit you will have the checked values, separated by commas in the `opt_0` and `opt_1` keys.

jQuery solution:

```
$('.registrant').each(function (index) {
    var attendee_reg_type = $(this).find('.reg_type:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(",");
    $("#opt_" + index).val(attendee_reg_type);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @SmartDev that actually fits my needs--I was over-thinking it. Although I'd still like to know if it's possible to populate the nth input field with the nth value of an array, as it'll be handy in the future.

Comment: @user3784298 You need `join(",")` for this. See updated answer.

Comment: The jQuery answer is exactly what I was looking for, @SmartDev !!!! Thank you for the assistance! Tried the solution in a fiddle others can view: http://jsfiddle.net/pn9zozto/